# Symfony2: enable absolute path to a folder, I am getting "...as such route does not exist"

Tags: .htaccess, symfony, path, routes, absolute

Good evening everybody,

I'm writing here because I think I have a basic problem. As I said, I think.

I'm actually working on a symfony2 project (my portfolio) and I have an issue since I pushed everything online.

The fact is that, as being a student, I would like to keep some files accessible through some urls targeting a specific folder on my server (to use it as a demo).

Let me give you more details. I have a page project. I'm setting an absolute url from the backend (i.e: www.example.com/project). The project folder itself is uploaded but when I try to access the url by clicking the link I've set I get this error:

"Unable to generate a URL for the named route "http://www.example.com/project" as such route does not exist".

Also in my twig I'm using

```
{{ path(project.link) }}
```

EDIT: project.link is the value entered in my backend (the url www.example.com/project) that I'm setting in my controller.

At this point I'm not really sure if it's about .htaccess file or the routing.php. Any idea?

EDIT:

here is the .htaccess I have in my web directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
    #    RewriteBase /
    #</IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<files php.ini>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</files>
```

Thanks in advance,

D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `project.link` is an already generated URL, then just do `{{ project.link }}`.

`{{ path() }}` is for generating a named route, for example in your routing.yml file.

As for the .htaccess file. Try changing it to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    #<IfModule mod_vhost_alias.c>
    #    RewriteBase /
    #</IfModule>

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>

<files php.ini>
  order deny,allow
  deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: project.link is actually the link itself as it is the object of my entity that I am trying to get from the database. Does that make sense?

Comment: What happens if you do `{{ project.link }}`?

Comment: the twig is well rendered but when I click the link I get this:

"No route found for "GET /project/www.example.com/gymtonic""

Comment: Oh and actually I've just figured out that it is adding the url to the one existing... which is bad anyway.

Comment: put http:// in front of it. E.g. `<a href="http://{{ project.link }}">Project</a>`. That will stop it being a relative path.

Comment: Actually I've just noticed that it is adding the url to the one existing... But the url www.example.com/project remains inaccessible (the project folder is at the root of the website at the same level than src etc...)

Comment: If it is an actual folder you will need to put it in the web directory. I'm not quite sure what you are trying to achieve. Really you should have a route setup in your routing.yml and serve it up using an action.

Comment: Ok there is progress.. Sorry I think our message were written in the same time..

So now. I can click the link and the url behave like expected. However I get this error :

"No route found for "GET /project/""

I think this is precisely why I ended here ;)

Comment: Same behavior in web directory, 404*

Comment: What is the contents of your project folder? Does it have an index.php or index.html? If so you will probably have to reference it by that file too as the default .htaccess with a Symfony install will route everything through app.php unless it is an absolute path to a file.

Comment: Yes, for example I have some basic prototypes in html. I'm getting confused really. I am really a beginner regarding the .htaccess and routing aspects to be honest.

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the web/.htaccess file please?

Comment: Alternatively, just update project.link in your database to be a direct path to the .html file. E.g. http://www.example.com/project/prototype.html

Comment: That's it! I can't believe it was that simple.. Thank you!
Otherwise I wonder how to enable the access to a folder. But let's close this topic ;)

Comment: your edit made the job ;) But the folder has to be in the web directory ;) many thanks (and sorry I can't vote yet :/)